# KLM with train segment from Schiphol to Brussels - take later Thalys train

Tags: tickets, amsterdam, brussels, klm, thalys

I have booked a ticket with KLM from Schiphol to Brussels with Thalys train (the flight it's from TLV to Schiphol and train from Schiphol to Brussels).

The time between the landing until the train time is 1 hour and 50 minuets.

I'm afraid this time not will be enough because it's my first time and maybe it's hard to find the train station and where I take the tickets. also If my first flight will be delayed the 1:50 hour maybe not will be enough.

If I will miss the train, can I take the next train (1 hour later) free of charge?

From your experience, 1 hour and 50 minuets it's enough?

**EDIT:**

1:50 hours it should be enough time, we succeeded to take the train and also we had 30 minuets to wait for the train :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no delays, in landing or in getting out of the airport, you should have plenty time enough. The railway station is part of the airport building with the platforms under the floor of the central arrivals area.

It takes about 5 minutes from where you pick up your luggage to the platform. Follow the 'train' signs and then look on the screens which platform to go.

If your train ticket is part of your airline ticket, the train company should honor it even if you are late due to the flight being delayed or the airport being slow for whatever reason.

Thalys is usually good in honoring tickets if you have a delay which you could not do anything about. It is not guarantied that they will honor a flight delay or an airport mess-up in passport control if you have a separately bought ticket, but if you are missing your train, go to one of the railway staff and ask.
If you miss your train and need to buy a new ticket, Thalys tickets are in the €80 range for 'same day' buys, but busy trains may be more expensive.  The less fast 'intercity trains' cost €45 and take an hour longer, but will not sell out.

Comment: (+1, lots of useful info...) I would not worry too much about this connection but regarding the fourth paragraph, that has not been my experience. Haven't tried in Schiphol but last time it happened to me, staff in Paris directed me to the hotline because it was a ticket issued by NS and the operator on the phone, while very nice, refused to do anything because I called about 5 minutes after the departure of the train.

Comment: Hi! Yesterday I arrived from my vacation, from TLV to AMS we succeeded to take the train so I don't have an answer to my question, but 2 hours it's enough, like said here, the train station it's 5 minutes walk from the airport. thank you all for your information!