# Is 2 hours enough at AMS to catch at train?

Tags: airport-transfer

Our flight arrives internationally into AMS at 08:38.   The train I need to catch from the airport terminal leaves at 10:30.  Is 2 hours enough time in these Covid times?  My first time traveling since COVID from Canada to Germany via Amsterdam airport and train to Germany.  Don't really want to buy the expensive ticket for the train in case I miss the time window.  My luggage is checked.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as it is an other train and to another country, but likely helpful: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138410/klm-with-train-segment-from-schiphol-to-brussels-take-later-thalys-train/143928#143928

Comment: Does your train to Germany leave from the airport train station or do you need to travel to an other station in Amsterdam first?

Answer (score 2):

> Is 2 hours enough time in these Covid times?

That should be plenty and unless there is a major hiccup you will be fine. AMS is a reasonably efficient airport and most Covid checks are done at departure.

However, it's never guaranteed and it always comes down to a risk assessment for your specific situation.

1. Coming in from Canada is also good since it is a "nice" country
2. Immigration proceedings depend a lot on what your citizenship is.
3. Not checking luggage will also speed things up considerably

All in all, for most "normal" situation this looks fine and personally I would be comfortable with it (and book it that way).

Comment: I have found that checked luggage does not add much time in Amsterdam. It is mostly waiting for you when you exit the passport control area. If that was fast it may take a few minutes.

Comment: @Willeke Exactly. Unlike how things are done in the US for example, in AMS you first have to walk to/queue for/pass immigration and only then walk to luggage claim and pick up your stuff there. Given the size of Schiphol, just the "walking" part is easily 10 minutes in total, plus immigration time. The bags are typically on the belt within 20 minutes of arrival.